# sql populate table with excel data

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

i am facing a problem getting data from whole excel spreadsheet into access table

Already tried that code:
`INSERT INTO Table1 IN " & CurrentDb.Name & "  SELECT * FROM" & strFile & "[Template$];"` 
but it doesn't work 
Then i used transferspradheet:
`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Table1", strFile, False, "Template$"`  ,but same result

Is there any option to paste data from excel into  access table by vba? or pasting whole recordset at once, without looping through fields and records?

I would like to make it generic, which means i dunno how many columns & rows   are in excel spreadsheets. My goal is to paste it to empty access table

Comment: You should post the error as well

Comment: field F8 doesnt exist in destination table "Table1" , thought to use recordset.fields.count and then by loop, add required  columns to access table by code. But still looking for simpler solution

Comment: I'd set the table up to accept a set amount of fields but allow any old rubbish to be imported, then use a series of append queries to push the data out to normalised tables.  If you're expecting the number of fields/columns to change continually then I expect you're thinking of a database as a big spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL syntax like this if table exists:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4) 
SELECT *
  FROM [Sheet1$D3:E24] 
    IN 'C:\Temp\MyData.xls' [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];
```

If you want to import whole spreadsheet into new table, use this:

```
SELECT * INTO Table1  FROM [Sheet1$] IN 'C:\Temp\MyData.xls' [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0];
```